# How can I access Gmail's native API?

Tags: google-api, gmail

I would like to access Gmail's native API. Eg,

- create a search folder
- tag messages
- other gmail-specific actions.

There's this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819528/gmail-plugin-api-development), however the question asker seems happy with developing contextual gadgets rather than actually accessing a user's email.

In before anyone mentions: **IMAP and POP are generic, non search based protocols and do not provide full access to gmail. Neither gmail.com, nor any of the official Gmail native apps, use IMAP and POP.**

Most webmail services have private, non-IMAP/POP APIs and protocols, eg, hotmail (back when it existed used HTTPMail which was reverse engineered and implemented by [hotwayd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hotwayd/)).

I could run Android gmail with a proxy and attempt to reverse engineer the Gmail protocol itself, but I suspect others have had the same need in the past and may already have a solution.

I did find a list of client of Gmail clients on [Gmail Agent API](http://johnvey.com/features/gmailapi/) but they don't seem maintained past 2004.

Comment: @user2284570 Yes I did. Did you read the bolded part of the question?

Comment: @user2284570 The question only pertains to email protocols. I do not wish to create gadgets or actions. As you may have read in the question.

Comment: Gmail's public API *is* IMAP. You can perform search and use folders through IMAP, though some operations require use of [Gmail's extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_gmail_labels_x-gm-labels). Labels are IMAP folders (which causes real IMAP clients to act funny with Gmail); stars (and I believe other tags, like colors) use [IMAP flags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107935/get-starred-messages-from-gmail-using-imap4-and-python). There is no account management via IMAP   or features like setting up automatic filters.

Comment: @rhashimoto As the question explicitly mentions I'm aware of this. My question is specifically about the private API that the Gmail web, iOS and Android apps use. Preforming search is not the same thing is search folders. IMAP is a leaky abstraction that official Gmail clients do not use.

Comment: This API seems to close the gap in IMAP + extensions, but I'm not sure if it is available to the public: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update June 2014**: Google have announced access to the native gmail API.

> The Gmail API gives you flexible, RESTful access to the user's inbox,
>   with a natural interface to Threads, Messages, Labels, Drafts, and
>   History. From the modern language of your choice, your app can use the
>   API to add Gmail features like:
>
> - Read messages from Gmail
> - Send email messages
> - Modify the labels applied to messages and threads
> - Search for specific messages and threads

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

Answer (score 3):

Android's Gmail app is using [**Google Cloud Messaging**](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) (GCM) to push email messages/notifications and sync with the phone. I think that’s “the API” you are looking for. The bad news is that it is obviously very well protected.

You can [get started for free](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) with GCM's JSON REST API and use it for your push messaging projects, but forget about using it for your Gmail in the same fashion Google does. The only option for getting a *similar* efficiency would be using [IMAP's IDLE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177) extension, which uses also push.

Focusing on what you need, I think there are decent solutions for the use cases you have listed in your question… You could use a [**Google App Script**][4] or libs like [**GMail for Python**][5], which seems a valid option to me... from the [**GMail for Python GitHub**][6]:

> **Features**
>
> - Search emails
> - Read emails
> - Emails: label, archive, delete, mark as read/unread/spam, star
> - Manage labels

If you are developing an Android mobile app **[Gmail Public Labels API](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html)** could also be of your interest...

Hope it helps...

---

**EDIT**: Google just introduced its **[GMAIL API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/)**

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a reference for gmail using GCM as a protocol? The Python client is just IMAP, so it can't for example, use search folders. But it would be possible to develop something using the native GCM, so I'm marking this as the accepted answer.